# offsettop and offsetleft for viewchildren

Tags: angular, offset, viewchild

I have a dynamically created component inside an *ngFor and how do I get the offsettop and offsetleft for those after getting them in a ViewChildren.

Template

```
<anchor #myanchor></anchor>
```

Class

```
@ViewChildren('myanchor') anchors: QueryList<any>;
```

Here is the ngAfterViewInit

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.anchors.map(i=>{ console.log(i); })
}
```

I am able to get the position for a single element through ViewChild but need help with ViewChildren. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```ts
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.anchors.toArray()
    .map(i=>{ console.log(i.nativeElement.offsetTop); })
}
```

If `#myanchor` is on a component or directive instead of a plain DOM element, you need to add `read` to get the `ElementRef`

```ts
@ViewChildren('myanchor', {read: ElementRef}) anchors: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

See also [angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681)

Comment: Thanks Gunter. The offsetTop or offsetHeight on the element are showing the relative height within the parent. Is there a way to get the absolute coordinates on the page?

Comment: I don't know, but it's the same as with plain JS.